# How to 'sanity check' a file on check in and discard the check in if file fails?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharepoint

Experienced .NET developer here (but only client object experience in SharePoint). Here's my scenario:

1. In SharePoint 2013 a user checks in an existing/new file after making changes
2. File check code (c# pref) is run against the file being checked in
3. If file passes checks continue check in
4. If file fails, discard check in, inform the user that the check in has failed & provide the reasons why it failed (reasons supplied by file check code).

I already have the file checks implemented as a c# class lib (used in a couple of other apps). I would like to be able to limit this to a specific folder (and all child folders within) and file type (identified by file extension).

What's the best practices method of implementing this?  My guess is to tie into existing SP events to determine check in and insert my file check class into that execution path.  In a perfect world I'd find a tutorial demonstrating this. :)

Thank you in advance for your time.

Regards,
Falconeer

Answer (score 0):

what you want is to develop a SharePoint farm solution which uses the event receivers. There are specific event receivers which will fire when someone checks in a document. Then you should do your logic there.

http://beginnersbook.com/2013/02/event-receivers-in-sharepoint/

Watch out for the event receivers - checkingin - checkedin. There is a difference between the two. The one is synchronous, the other asynchronous. I would put your logic in the -ing event receiver as this allows you to cancel the checkin.

You might have to play with before and afterproperties to do the appropriate check on folder, file, etc...

http://www.sharepointalex.co.uk/index.php/2010/06/beforepropertiesafterproperties-in-event-receivers-i-always-forget-this/

This should be the way to go!

Comment: I'll investigate the event receivers.  Thanks!